# Flexbox positioning everything the same way. Any way to make it act differently?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've some code that is autogenerated with one of my tools. It generates HTML/CSS and JS. It generated this little dashboard like on a screenshot:

[image]

It's based on flexbox as it allows me to position tables easily but the drawback is it actually positions anything that way. Adding simple text that I would like to have over the table positions it the same ways as it does to the tables. Which is less than optimal.

How could I make it work so that text or eventually other kinds of data can be positioned over the table?

Full code here: https://codepen.io/przemyslawklys/pen/xevoJN

Relevant part:

CSS:

```
    <style type="text/css">
         div.defaultSection {
            border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
            margin: 5px;
            width: calc(100% - 10px);
            overflow: hidden;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: hidden;
        }

        div.defaultColumn {
            overflow: hidden;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: hidden;
            padding: 2px;
        }

        .defaultContainer {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            padding: 2px;
            overflow: hidden;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: hidden;
        }

        .defaultContainerOther {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            overflow: hidden;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: hidden;
        }

        .defaultPanelOther {
            flex-basis: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: hidden;
        }

        .defaultPanel {
            flex-basis: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: hidden;
        }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
        <div id="15301525" class="defaultContainerOther">
            <div class="defaultContainer defaultPanelOther collapsable" id="15301525">
                <div><span>My Text1</span></div>
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function () {


                        //  Table code
                        var table = $('#DT-zHuCxhCV').DataTable({
                            "dom": "Bfrtip",
                            "buttons": [
                                "copyHtml5",
                                "excelHtml5",
                                "csvHtml5",
                                "pdfHtml5"
                            ],
                            "colReorder": true,
                            "paging": true,
                            "scrollCollapse": false,
                            "pagingType": [
                                "full_numbers"
                            ],
                            "lengthMenu": [
                                [
                                    15,
                                    25,
                                    50,
                                    100
                                ],
                                -1,
                                [
                                    15,
                                    25,
                                    50,
                                    100
                                ],
                                "All"
                            ],
                            "ordering": true,
                            "order": [

                            ],
                            "info": true,
                            "procesing": true,
                            "responsive": {
                                "details": true
                            },
                            "select": true,
                            "searching": true,
                            "stateSave": true
                        });

                    });
                </script>
                <div class="defaultPanelOther">
                    <table id="DT-zHuCxhCV" class="display compact">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>PriorityClass</th>
                                <th>FileVersion</th>
                                <th>HandleCount</th>
                                <th>WorkingSet</th>
                                <th>PagedMemorySize</th>
                                <th>PrivateMemorySize</th>
                                <th>VirtualMemorySize</th>
                                <th>TotalProcessorTime</th>
                                <th>SI</th>
                                <th>Handles</th>
                                <th>VM</th>
                                <th>WS</th>
                                <th>PM</th>
                                <th>NPM</th>
                                <th>Path</th>
                                <th>Company</th>
                                <th>CPU</th>
                                <th>ProductVersion</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Product</th>
                                <th>__NounName</th>
                                <th>BasePriority</th>
                                <th>ExitCode</th>
                                <th>HasExited</th>
                                <th>ExitTime</th>
                                <th>Handle</th>
                                <th>SafeHandle</th>
                                <th>MachineName</th>
                                <th>MainWindowHandle</th>
                                <th>MainWindowTitle</th>
                                <th>MainModule</th>
                                <th>MaxWorkingSet</th>
                                <th>MinWorkingSet</th>
                                <th>Modules</th>
                                <th>NonpagedSystemMemorySize</th>
                                <th>NonpagedSystemMemorySize64</th>
                                <th>PagedMemorySize64</th>
                                <th>PagedSystemMemorySize</th>
                                <th>PagedSystemMemorySize64</th>
                                <th>PeakPagedMemorySize</th>
                                <th>PeakPagedMemorySize64</th>
                                <th>PeakWorkingSet</th>
                                <th>PeakWorkingSet64</th>
                                <th>PeakVirtualMemorySize</th>
                                <th>PeakVirtualMemorySize64</th>
                                <th>PriorityBoostEnabled</th>
                                <th>PrivateMemorySize64</th>
                                <th>PrivilegedProcessorTime</th>
                                <th>ProcessName</th>
                                <th>ProcessorAffinity</th>
                                <th>Responding</th>
                                <th>SessionId</th>
                                <th>StartInfo</th>
                                <th>StartTime</th>
                                <th>SynchronizingObject</th>
                                <th>Threads</th>
                                <th>UserProcessorTime</th>
                                <th>VirtualMemorySize64</th>
                                <th>EnableRaisingEvents</th>
                                <th>StandardInput</th>
                                <th>StandardOutput</th>
                                <th>StandardError</th>
                                <th>WorkingSet64</th>
                                <th>Site</th>
                                <th>Container</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1Password</td>
                                <td>16904</td>
                                <td>Normal</td>
                                <td>7.3.684</td>
                                <td>743</td>
                                <td>40570880</td>
                                <td>48590848</td>
                                <td>48590848</td>
                                <td>302575616</td>
                                <td>00:00:01.1718750</td>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>743</td>
                                <td>302575616</td>
                                <td>40570880</td>
                                <td>48590848</td>
                                <td>39640</td>
                                <td>C:\Users\przemyslaw.klys\AppData\Local\1password\app\7\1Password.exe</td>
                                <td>AgileBits Inc.</td>
                                <td>1,171875</td>
                                <td>7.3.684</td>
                                <td>1Password for Windows desktop</td>
                                <td>1Password</td>
                                <td>Process</td>
                                <td>8</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>False</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>7856</td>
                                <td>Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeProcessHandle</td>
                                <td>.</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>System.Diagnostics.ProcessModule (1Password.exe)</td>
                                <td>1413120</td>
                                <td>204800</td>
                                <td>System.Diagnostics.ProcessModuleCollection</td>
                                <td>39640</td>
                                <td>39640</td>
                                <td>48590848</td>
                                <td>459488</td>
                                <td>459488</td>
                                <td>49123328</td>
                                <td>49123328</td>
                                <td>61747200</td>
                                <td>61747200</td>
                                <td>326172672</td>
                                <td>326172672</td>
                                <td>True</td>
                                <td>48590848</td>
                                <td>00:00:00.4375000</td>
                                <td>1Password</td>
                                <td>65535</td>
                                <td>True</td>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo</td>
                                <td>01.05.2019 21:11:22</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>System.Diagnostics.ProcessThreadCollection</td>
                                <td>00:00:00.7343750</td>
                                <td>302575616</td>
                                <td>False</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>40570880</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>PriorityClass</th>
                                <th>FileVersion</th>
                                <th>HandleCount</th>
                                <th>WorkingSet</th>
                                <th>PagedMemorySize</th>
                                <th>PrivateMemorySize</th>
                                <th>VirtualMemorySize</th>
                                <th>TotalProcessorTime</th>
                                <th>SI</th>
                                <th>Handles</th>
                                <th>VM</th>
                                <th>WS</th>
                                <th>PM</th>
                                <th>NPM</th>
                                <th>Path</th>
                                <th>Company</th>
                                <th>CPU</th>
                                <th>ProductVersion</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Product</th>
                                <th>__NounName</th>
                                <th>BasePriority</th>
                                <th>ExitCode</th>
                                <th>HasExited</th>
                                <th>ExitTime</th>
                                <th>Handle</th>
                                <th>SafeHandle</th>
                                <th>MachineName</th>
                                <th>MainWindowHandle</th>
                                <th>MainWindowTitle</th>
                                <th>MainModule</th>
                                <th>MaxWorkingSet</th>
                                <th>MinWorkingSet</th>
                                <th>Modules</th>
                                <th>NonpagedSystemMemorySize</th>
                                <th>NonpagedSystemMemorySize64</th>
                                <th>PagedMemorySize64</th>
                                <th>PagedSystemMemorySize</th>
                                <th>PagedSystemMemorySize64</th>
                                <th>PeakPagedMemorySize</th>
                                <th>PeakPagedMemorySize64</th>
                                <th>PeakWorkingSet</th>
                                <th>PeakWorkingSet64</th>
                                <th>PeakVirtualMemorySize</th>
                                <th>PeakVirtualMemorySize64</th>
                                <th>PriorityBoostEnabled</th>
                                <th>PrivateMemorySize64</th>
                                <th>PrivilegedProcessorTime</th>
                                <th>ProcessName</th>
                                <th>ProcessorAffinity</th>
                                <th>Responding</th>
                                <th>SessionId</th>
                                <th>StartInfo</th>
                                <th>StartTime</th>
                                <th>SynchronizingObject</th>
                                <th>Threads</th>
                                <th>UserProcessorTime</th>
                                <th>VirtualMemorySize64</th>
                                <th>EnableRaisingEvents</th>
                                <th>StandardInput</th>
                                <th>StandardOutput</th>
                                <th>StandardError</th>
                                <th>WorkingSet64</th>
                                <th>Site</th>
                                <th>Container</th>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div><span>My Text2</span></div>
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function () {


                        //  Table code
                        var table = $('#DT-BTfLHCYx').DataTable({
                            "dom": "Bfrtip",
                            "buttons": [
                                "copyHtml5",
                                "excelHtml5",
                                "csvHtml5",
                                "pdfHtml5"
                            ],
                            "colReorder": true,
                            "paging": true,
                            "scrollCollapse": false,
                            "pagingType": [
                                "full_numbers"
                            ],
                            "lengthMenu": [
                                [
                                    15,
                                    25,
                                    50,
                                    100
                                ],
                                -1,
                                [
                                    15,
                                    25,
                                    50,
                                    100
                                ],
                                "All"
                            ],
                            "ordering": true,
                            "order": [

                            ],
                            "info": true,
                            "procesing": true,
                            "responsive": {
                                "details": true
                            },
                            "select": true,
                            "searching": true,
                            "stateSave": true
                        });

                    });
                </script>
                <div class="defaultPanelOther">
                    <table id="DT-BTfLHCYx" class="display compact">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>PriorityClass</th>
                                <th>FileVersion</th>
                                <th>HandleCount</th>
                                <th>WorkingSet</th>
                                <th>PagedMemorySize</th>
                                <th>PrivateMemorySize</th>
                                <th>VirtualMemorySize</th>
                                <th>TotalProcessorTime</th>
                                <th>SI</th>
                                <th>Handles</th>
                                <th>VM</th>
                                <th>WS</th>
                                <th>PM</th>
                                <th>NPM</th>
                                <th>Path</th>
                                <th>Company</th>
                                <th>CPU</th>
                                <th>ProductVersion</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Product</th>
                                <th>__NounName</th>
                                <th>BasePriority</th>
                                <th>ExitCode</th>
                                <th>HasExited</th>
                                <th>ExitTime</th>
                                <th>Handle</th>
                                <th>SafeHandle</th>
                                <th>MachineName</th>
                                <th>MainWindowHandle</th>
                                <th>MainWindowTitle</th>
                                <th>MainModule</th>
                                <th>MaxWorkingSet</th>
                                <th>MinWorkingSet</th>
                                <th>Modules</th>
                                <th>NonpagedSystemMemorySize</th>
                                <th>NonpagedSystemMemorySize64</th>
                                <th>PagedMemorySize64</th>
                                <th>PagedSystemMemorySize</th>
                                <th>PagedSystemMemorySize64</th>
                                <th>PeakPagedMemorySize</th>
                                <th>PeakPagedMemorySize64</th>
                                <th>PeakWorkingSet</th>
                                <th>PeakWorkingSet64</th>
                                <th>PeakVirtualMemorySize</th>
                                <th>PeakVirtualMemorySize64</th>
                                <th>PriorityBoostEnabled</th>
                                <th>PrivateMemorySize64</th>
                                <th>PrivilegedProcessorTime</th>
                                <th>ProcessName</th>
                                <th>ProcessorAffinity</th>
                                <th>Responding</th>
                                <th>SessionId</th>
                                <th>StartInfo</th>
                                <th>StartTime</th>
                                <th>SynchronizingObject</th>
                                <th>Threads</th>
                                <th>UserProcessorTime</th>
                                <th>VirtualMemorySize64</th>
                                <th>EnableRaisingEvents</th>
                                <th>StandardInput</th>
                                <th>StandardOutput</th>
                                <th>StandardError</th>
                                <th>WorkingSet64</th>
                                <th>Site</th>
                                <th>Container</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1Password</td>
                                <td>16904</td>
                                <td>Normal</td>
                                <td>7.3.684</td>
                                <td>743</td>
                                <td>40570880</td>
                                <td>48590848</td>
                                <td>48590848</td>
                                <td>302575616</td>
                                <td>00:00:01.1718750</td>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>743</td>
                                <td>302575616</td>
                                <td>40570880</td>
                                <td>48590848</td>
                                <td>39640</td>
                                <td>C:\Users\przemyslaw.klys\AppData\Local\1password\app\7\1Password.exe</td>
                                <td>AgileBits Inc.</td>
                                <td>1,171875</td>
                                <td>7.3.684</td>
                                <td>1Password for Windows desktop</td>
                                <td>1Password</td>
                                <td>Process</td>
                                <td>8</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>False</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>7856</td>
                                <td>Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeProcessHandle</td>
                                <td>.</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>System.Diagnostics.ProcessModule (1Password.exe)</td>
                                <td>1413120</td>
                                <td>204800</td>
                                <td>System.Diagnostics.ProcessModuleCollection</td>
                                <td>39640</td>
                                <td>39640</td>
                                <td>48590848</td>
                                <td>459488</td>
                                <td>459488</td>
                                <td>49123328</td>
                                <td>49123328</td>
                                <td>61747200</td>
                                <td>61747200</td>
                                <td>326172672</td>
                                <td>326172672</td>
                                <td>True</td>
                                <td>48590848</td>
                                <td>00:00:00.4375000</td>
                                <td>1Password</td>
                                <td>65535</td>
                                <td>True</td>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo</td>
                                <td>01.05.2019 21:11:22</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>System.Diagnostics.ProcessThreadCollection</td>
                                <td>00:00:00.7343750</td>
                                <td>302575616</td>
                                <td>False</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>40570880</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>PriorityClass</th>
                                <th>FileVersion</th>
                                <th>HandleCount</th>
                                <th>WorkingSet</th>
                                <th>PagedMemorySize</th>
                                <th>PrivateMemorySize</th>
                                <th>VirtualMemorySize</th>
                                <th>TotalProcessorTime</th>
                                <th>SI</th>
                                <th>Handles</th>
                                <th>VM</th>
                                <th>WS</th>
                                <th>PM</th>
                                <th>NPM</th>
                                <th>Path</th>
                                <th>Company</th>
                                <th>CPU</th>
                                <th>ProductVersion</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Product</th>
                                <th>__NounName</th>
                                <th>BasePriority</th>
                                <th>ExitCode</th>
                                <th>HasExited</th>
                                <th>ExitTime</th>
                                <th>Handle</th>
                                <th>SafeHandle</th>
                                <th>MachineName</th>
                                <th>MainWindowHandle</th>
                                <th>MainWindowTitle</th>
                                <th>MainModule</th>
                                <th>MaxWorkingSet</th>
                                <th>MinWorkingSet</th>
                                <th>Modules</th>
                                <th>NonpagedSystemMemorySize</th>
                                <th>NonpagedSystemMemorySize64</th>
                                <th>PagedMemorySize64</th>
                                <th>PagedSystemMemorySize</th>
                                <th>PagedSystemMemorySize64</th>
                                <th>PeakPagedMemorySize</th>
                                <th>PeakPagedMemorySize64</th>
                                <th>PeakWorkingSet</th>
                                <th>PeakWorkingSet64</th>
                                <th>PeakVirtualMemorySize</th>
                                <th>PeakVirtualMemorySize64</th>
                                <th>PriorityBoostEnabled</th>
                                <th>PrivateMemorySize64</th>
                                <th>PrivilegedProcessorTime</th>
                                <th>ProcessName</th>
                                <th>ProcessorAffinity</th>
                                <th>Responding</th>
                                <th>SessionId</th>
                                <th>StartInfo</th>
                                <th>StartTime</th>
                                <th>SynchronizingObject</th>
                                <th>Threads</th>
                                <th>UserProcessorTime</th>
                                <th>VirtualMemorySize64</th>
                                <th>EnableRaisingEvents</th>
                                <th>StandardInput</th>
                                <th>StandardOutput</th>
                                <th>StandardError</th>
                                <th>WorkingSet64</th>
                                <th>Site</th>
                                <th>Container</th>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: flexbox is not really a suitable replacement for tables. I'd prefer to use the right tool for the job.

Comment: It does work correctly for my needs. It's just hard to position anything else differently within those containers. I am able to create proper Dashboard with it. Also proposing alternatives is more helpful than saying it's not the right tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the structure:

Don't add the text in `.defaultContainer.defaultPanelOther.collapsable` but in the child `.defaultPanelOther`

Change

```
<div class="defaultContainer defaultPanelOther collapsable" id="15301525">
  <script>/* ... */</script>
  <div><span>My Text1</span></div>
  <div class="defaultPanelOther"><!-- ... --></div>
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="defaultContainer defaultPanelOther collapsable" id="15301525">
  <script>/* ... */</script>
  <div class="defaultPanelOther">
    <div><span>My Text1</span></div><!-- <<<--- Moved into -->
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</div>
```

See `https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/ZZggeN`